# XML file for High Scores in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am creating simple memory game in c# using sharp develop or Visual Studio, and my task is to save 10 best high scores in xml file, well i never used xml file in c# for data storage so if anyone can explain how to create xml and use it ,  it would be most helpful !

Comment: use xmlserialize instead .it be easy

Comment: What would be helpful is to know a little more about what your trying to serialise (store) - how you would like it to work etc.  And code examples are always good!  I'd add these quickly or your likely to receive a load of mark downs and then have your question closed.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: This site is NOT called homeworkoverflow. Do you think you're the only person in the world who'se seen that question in an assignment?

Comment: Yeah you are wright, but i had a lot of trouble with that xml file, but i think i've done it now with a help of an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this.

```
    public class HighScore
    {
        public int Score
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public class HighScoreCollection : List<HighScore>
    {
        public void SaveToXml(string fileName)
        {
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileName))
            {
                XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(HighScoreCollection));
                ser.Serialize(writer, this);
                writer.Flush();
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```